# Does the scope handle exceptions/failures silently under the hood?

Tags: kotlin, exception, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following snippet for testing purposes;

```
fun main() {

   val myScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) + Job()

   myScope.launch {

       val job = async {
           delay(1000)
           throw RuntimeException("shiiiet")
       }

       try {
           job.await()
       } catch (ret: RuntimeException){
           throw RuntimeException("yooo!")
       }
   }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000)
    } catch(e: Exception){

    }

    println("wohoooo!") 
}
```

I thought the flow would never reach the last "wohooo!" line but I was wrong. I see it's printed on the screen. The reason I had in my mind that `launch` would propagate the exception to the parent scope and since the parent scope does not handle it, it would crash the JVM by the time it reaches the print statement.

Is this because the parent scope got cancelled once it's child failed, received a CancellationException and it was ignored?

Comment: A failed top-level `launch` doesn't crash the JVM, and it isn't supposed to. A crashed thread doesn't crash the JVM, either.

Comment: That is true but I somehow thought the exception would be propagated all the way up to the main thread by the scope.

Comment: The Default dispatcher is not in charge of the main thread. On plain Java the main thread doesn't even run an event loop and thus can't dispatch coroutines at all. You must explicitly create an event loop on it with runBlocking.

Answer (score 0):

You tried multiple `throw`and `catch` approaches in your example.

`async` works as expected - when you `await` for it, you can catch the exception. But if you `launch` a co-routine, the default `Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler` just prints the result to console.

Even if you do

```
myScope.launch {
    ....
}.invokeOnCompletion { e -> println("Exception: $e") }
```

you still get the result additionally on console.

The propagation rules and the different types of calls to handle the exceptions are explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html).

An example on how to catch an exception in the "main" co-routine:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    try {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(10)
            throw Exception("You don't catch me in main.")
        }
        launch {
            delay(10)
            throw Exception("You catch me in main.")
        }
        delay(100)
        println("Never reached.")
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        println("Caught in main: ${e.cause}")
    }
    println("The end")
}
```

Comment: Your code always prints `Never reached!`, as well as `You can't see me.` Furthermore, `Dispatchers.Unconfined` doesn't use the "main context", whatever that is supposed to mean, it starts and resumes the coroutine right where `launch` and `resume` is called, within those calls, without any thread confinement.

Comment: Ups, With `You can't see me` I meant `You don't catch me in main()`.... I need to look into the Dispatchers again. Give me a few hours...

Comment: You can't possibly catch an exception from a concurrently launched coroutine in a thread that has gone on to do other things. It is only by the accident of null-dispatch that you would see an exception thrown from `launch(Unconfined)` due to the above, that it executes without dispatching. That behavior would disappear as soon as the coroutine suspends, for example if you add `delay(10)` before throwing the exception. However, I can't catch the exception from `launch` even without suspending.

Comment: @Mark After some more reading and testing I removed the faulty part of my answer. Thanks for pointing that out. I added an example on how to catch with "main co-routine"...

Comment: What you did is catch the `CancellationException` that resulted from a failing child coroutine. You didn't catch and handle the original exception, you just got it attached as the cause of cancellation. The line of code that threw `CancellationException` is `delay(100)` because it's a cancellable suspending call. However, this didn't stop the `runBlocking` scope from failing so this doesn't actually constitute exception handling.

Comment: Furthermore, it is a programming error to catch and swallow a `CancellationException` like that, it just breaks the structured concurrency discipline.